# Magento 1.8.1.0 and Pay Pal Error 10413

Tags: magento-1.8, error, paypal, tax, rounding

After spending weeks on trying to fix this in Magento 1.7.1.0, I decided to update to 1.8.1.0 to finally get rid of this problem and guess what - nothing has changed!
I am still getting the "The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts." error and my customers can still not checkout using PayPal in some cases. Tax is set up exactly as recommended here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-ce-18-ee-113-tax-calc
The issue again is the pesky 1 cent and the only information I could find that made some sense to me is this: https://gist.github.com/edannenberg/8041401

Since you can't even report bugs for Magento 1.8.1.0 (obviously considered to be bugfree...) and no moderator on the official forums ever gave a c*** about this nasty problem, I would like to ask you guys, if you are aswell still experiencing this issue in Magento 1.8.1.0

UPDATE:
After reapplying this fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868985/magento-paypal-tax-rounding-issue#answer-14562319 on my 1.8.1.0 install and setting transfer cart line items to No, I have had no more paypal errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can try our fix:

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/PaypalRoundBugfix

Afaik the problem with

> setting transfer cart line items to No

is, that PayPal doesn't then insure your stuff against the customer, so if you are a fraud, the customer doesn'T get their money back from paypal - AFAIK.